# Ajax url with parameter. The current path didn’t match any of these

Tags: django, ajax

I'm new in django. I try to delete element from database by ajax call. My ajax call send url with parameter which is `pk` of element to delete. Url looks fine but browser raise error that
url pattern doesn't match to any of urlpatterns in my `url.py`.
I have done similar project before and everything workerd good so I'm confused why it does't work now. Any Idea?

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home,name='home'),
    path('mojerec',views.mojeRec,name='mojerec'),
    path('dodajrec',views.dodajRec,name='dodajrec'),
    path('receptura/(<int:receptura_id>)',views.receptura,name='receptura'),
    path('formJson/<str:skl>/', views.formJson, name='formJson'),
    path('receptura/formJson/<str:skl>/', views.formJson, name='formJson'),
    path('receptura/dodajskl/<str:sklId>/', views.dodajsklJson, name='dodajsklJson'),
    path('receptura/aktualizujTabela/<str:sklId>/', views.aktualizujTabela, name='aktualizujTabela'),
    path('receptuta/delSkl/<int:id>/', views.delSkl, name='delSkl'),


]
```

views.py

```
def delSkl (request,id):
    deletedElement=Skladnik.objects.filter(pk=id)
    response=serializers.serialize("python", deletedElement)
    deletedElement.delete()
    print('response', response)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return JsonResponse({'response':response})
```

myjs.js

```
function usuwanieSkladnika (pk){
        $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: `delSkl/${ pk }/`,
                        success : function(response){console.log('sukces ajaxa z del');
                        cardBox.innerHTML=''
                        tabelaDocelowa.innerHTML='';
                        updateTable()

                        },//koniec sukcesa
                        error : function (error){console.log('brak sukcesu ajaxa z del')},
                        })

}
```

log:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/receptura/delSkl/13/

Using the URLconf defined in recipe.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    [name='home']
    mojerec [name='mojerec']
    dodajrec [name='dodajrec']
    receptura/(<int:receptura_id>) [name='receptura']
    formJson/<str:skl>/ [name='formJson']
    receptura/formJson/<str:skl>/ [name='formJson']
    receptura/dodajskl/<str:sklId>/ [name='dodajsklJson']
    receptura/aktualizujTabela/<str:sklId>/ [name='aktualizujTabela']
    receptuta/delSkl/<int:id>/ [name='delSkl']
    users/

The current path, receptura/delSkl/13/, didn’t match any of these.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo error in your `urls.py` i.e. you have `receptuta/delSkl/<int:id>/` in your `urls.py` and you are calling `receptura/delSkl/<int:id>/`

Change your `urls.py` from :

```
path('receptuta/delSkl/<int:id>/', views.delSkl, name='delSkl'),
```

To this:

```
path('receptura/delSkl/<int:id>/', views.delSkl, name='delSkl'),
```